# jquery cookie и curl

Tags: jquery, curl, php, cookie

Добрый вечер, проблема в следующем: сайт выставляет cookie через jquery. Проблема в том что не могу curl-ом получить эти самые куки.
Подскажите возможный/ные вариант решения проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну jquery тут лишне, просто JavaScript. 
Вариант только 1, найти код выставления и скопировать алгоритм создания и эмулировать его.

Вот, почитайте про одну из реализаций этого:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/133191/